# Seria "Promise.all" (e outras funções similares) um exemplo de paralelismo em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promises, paralelismo

Em JavaScript, temos o [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), que resolve um array de promessas em uma única [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Esse processo é aparentemente *paralelo*, já que as promessas são resolvidas ao mesmo tempo, e não de forma linear.

Além do `Promise.all`, outras funções como [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) e [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) também possuem um comportamento similar de executar as promessas "ao mesmo tempo", resolvendo em uma só `Promise`.

Mas isso realmente é um tipo de **paralelismo** no JavaScript? Como isso realmente funciona?

---

Um exemplo que compara as promessas resolvendo-se de forma linear e *paralela*, respectivamente:

```js
// Irá demorar 500ms para dobrar o número.
const double = (num) => new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(num * 2), 500)
);

(async () => {
  const doubles = [];
  
  const start = Date.now();
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    doubles.push(await double(i));
  }
  
  console.log(doubles);
  console.log(`Finished in ${Date.now() - start}ms.`);
})();
```

```js
const double = (num) => new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(num * 2), 500)
);

(async () => {
  const nums = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => i + 1);
  
  const start = Date.now();
  const doubles = await Promise.all(nums.map(double));
  
  console.log(doubles);
  console.log(`Finished in ${Date.now() - start}ms.`);
})();
```

Comment: O JavaScript não é multithread, sendo assim, não tem como ocorrer o paralelismo (que é a execução **simultânea**). O que acontece é que os códigos são executados **alternadamente**, enquanto é esperado a execução do callback do `setTimeout` outras coisas podem ser executadas. O 1° `await` diz que o retorno da função deve ser aguardado para então continuar o loop, enquanto o 2° cria as promessas e depois aplica a espera, ou seja, no 1° cria e espera o retorna de cada promessa antes de ir pra próxima, no outro, a espera é aplicada depois que todas promessas são iniciadas e já estão esperando

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na verdade, o paralelismo (ou inexistência dele) reside nas promises em si, não no Promise.all(). O trabalho de uma promise começa quando ela é criada, o que `Promise.all(doubles)` faz é criar uma promise que finaliza sua execução assim que todas as promises recebidas (**doubles**) foram finalizadas.

No primeiro trecho de código você chama

```
doubles.push(await double(i))
```

dentro do loop, obrigando cada ciclo esperar a resolução da promise, mas não precisa fazer isso; poderia chamar

```
doubles.push(double(i))
```

permitindo que `double()` comece a executar assincronamente, quiçá de forma concorrente; e depois fazer await na promise criada com `Promise.all(doubles)`.

Uma das grandes vantagens de usar `Promise.all()` é receber uma exceção mais cedo se alguma promise falhar, além de esperar no máximo o tempo da promise mais demorada dentro de **doubles**.

O Node.js possui um thread pool interno para que operações assíncronas bloqueantes possam correr em paralelo. Mas esse pool está fora do alcance do código Javascript. Promises e operações assíncronas que sejam implementadas em Javascript puro (sem invocar um módulo escrito em C++ que poderia fazer uso da thread pool) não poderão executar de forma concorrente.