# SetTimeout executa em paralelo no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Estou estudando sobre os conceitos de assincronismo, sei que o Node.js é *single-threaded* e que para alguns tipos de tarefa ele delega a mesma para o `libuv` (que possui 4 *threads* por padrão) e outras para o próprio gerenciador de *threads* do sistema operacional. No entanto, que ao testar um trecho de código usando várias chamadas de `setTimeout` o `console.time()` retorna 1 segundo para todas elas. O `setTimeout` é executado em paralelo?

O que entendi sobre o *event loop* é que ele vai "empilhando" tarefas assíncronas e as executa em sequência, mas não entendi por que vários `setTimeout`s agendados para executar após 1 segundo são retornados ao mesmo tempo.

Trecho de código:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(a + b)
        }, 1000)
    })
}

console.time('start')
Promise.all([
    sum(1, 2),
    sum(3, 5),
    sum(3, 5),
    sum(3, 5),
    sum(3, 5),
    sum(3, 5),
    sum(3, 5),
]).then(res => {
    console.timeEnd("start")
})
```

Saída:

```
start: 1004.434ms
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Seria "Promise.all" (e outros métodos similares) um exemplo de paralelismo em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437878/seria-promise-all-e-outros-m%c3%a9todos-similares-um-exemplo-de-paralelismo-em-ja)

Comment: obrigado, mas gerou mais dúvidas rs

Comment: :P Está falando dessa pergunta linkada ou da resposta? Se for dessa última, tente explicar o porquê para eu ver se consigo dar mais detalhes ou recapitular. :-)

Comment: era da pergunta linkada rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SetTimeout executa em paralelo no NodeJS?

Não. No JavaScript não existe paralelismo. Pelo menos não até a introdução dos *Worker threads* no Node.js ou os WebWorkers no navegador. Aí sim pode-se considerar paralelismo, mas no JavaScript "puro", como no código da pergunta, não.

O que está fazendo parecer que é paralelo é um artifício do `Promise.all`, que aguarda a resolução de todas as promessas para se resolver.

Desse modo, quando você cria o *array* literal:

> ```
> [
>     sum(1, 2),
>     sum(3, 5),
>     sum(3, 5),
>     sum(3, 5),
>     sum(3, 5),
>     sum(3, 5),
>     sum(3, 5),
> ]
> ```

Você está invocando a função `sum` 6 vezes, de modo que uma será chamada logo após a outra. Algo assim:

- Chame `sum` com `1` e `2`;
- Chame `sum` com `3` e `5`;
- ...

Desse modo, você pode perceber que elas não estão sendo invocadas em paralelo, mas sim sequencialmente. Note, no entanto, que todas elas retornam uma `Promise`. Como todas as funções foram executadas quase ao mesmo tempo, todas as promessas resolver-se-ão um segundo depois, o que resolverá `Promise.all`, quase 1 segundo após o início do script.

Os `4.434ms` restantes são, em parte, devido à execução das funções de forma síncrona, de modo que a última é invocada algumas frações de segundo depois da primeira. É quase instantâneo. Além disso, existe também o processo de resolução das promessas. A "mensagem" de resolução das promessas é passada sequencialmente para `Promise.all`, o que adiciona mais algumas frações de segundo.

O *loop de eventos* agenda, processa e devolve apenas um item por vez (a ordem dessas ações pode variar, como no código da pergunta) e `setTimeout`, outros *timers*, promessas ou `Promise.all` não são exceções a essa regra.

Para saber mais sobre esse "quase paralelismo" de `Promise.all` (e outros agregadores de `Promise` similares), veja [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437878/seria-promise-all-e-outros-m%C3%A9todos-similares-um-exemplo-de-paralelismo-em-ja).

Comment: Entendi, então ,a grosso modo, pode-se dizer todas são agendadas no event-loop quase no mesmo tempo e também acabam quase no mesmo tempo, os "números quebrados" é o tempo que o event loop envia as "mensagens", certo?  Eu acho que confundi o agendamento no event-loop com o tempo de execução, apartir do tempo que é enviado pro event-loop já começa a contagem, certo?

Comment: Basicamente é isso sim. Só não entendi a qual "contagem" você se refere. Se for o tempo do `setTimeout`, sim.

Comment: Isso, seria a contagem regressiva do setTimeout.
Obrigado!